# S3 Presigned URL GET request returns 403 but the link is accessible in the browser

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3

To display a video on a webpage that's too large to host on github I'm using amazon s3. I have a presigned URL with 12 hour validity. When I paste the link into the broswer it works just fine, bbut when I make the request through my web app I get a 403 error.

This is a the request in React:

```
const url = 'presignedlink'
...
<Image src={url} ... />
```

Any clue? I have read something about request headers, but I'm not sure how to pass those to an image component. The file in question is a gif if that helps.

Comment: You got any solution ?